# How to develop Java webapps in a Ruby on Rails-like way?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, ruby-on-rails-3

We've got an app that needs to run in a Java app server. I've got to develop a webapp to go with it. I've started reading about Ruby on Rails, and I really like the approach: MVC, convention over configuration, tons of stuff taken care of for you.

I may be dreaming the impossible dream, but are there any Java webapp development frameworks out there that work in a similar way?

Straight JSP is miserable, because logic and presentation are mixed. Simple template systems, like Velocity and Freemarker don't do the database stuff. I don't know much about Spring.

Everybody here knows Java, and we don't have time before the next release cycle to learn an entirely new language and library, else I'd plunge into RoR in a serious way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not impossible at all. It's already been done.

Here are a few Java-equivalents:

- Grails http://www.grails.org/
- SpringRoo. http://www.springsource.org/roo
- Spring MVC. http://www.springsource.org/

All are products of SpringSource. If you're getting serious about Java web development, I highly recommend you check them out.

Grails was actually inspired by Rails, hence the name, so you'll see many similarities in features and paradigms between the two, including MVC, convention-over-configuration, and code generation. So if you're looking to get right into Rails-like development in Java, I highly recommend Grails. I should note that Grails has more features than Rails, some of which I think Rails should adopt. An example is Grails provides a service layer to handle all business logic. You could easily implement a service layer in Rails, but its convenience we all love, and because Grails includes it, it is more convenient.  I've hopped between Rails and Grails once upon a time, both great frameworks.

Keep in mind that you can do Rails development with Java as well, via JRuby, which is not a bad option either. You get all the features of the Ruby language (v. 1.8), along with the ability to integrate and use Java libraries within your Ruby code.

SpringRoo is SpringSource's new code generator framework, so you can use it with the Spring framework to aid in agile/rapid application development.

Grails is actually built on-top of the Spring framework and Groovy. Groovy is Java-derivative which looks more like a scripting language and provides all the meta/dynamic programming goodness that you see in languages such as Ruby and Python. However, Groovy allows you to write Java code as well, so there's no need to learn it, not entirely at least.

Comment: worth noting that SpringRoo and Spring MVC still require a fairly large amount of annotation or XML config, and creating the layout. In fact pretty much everything is up to you -- Spring Boot is finally bringing more config-ready abilities to Spring MVC, but **still**, you must create the directory layout, make models and controllers by hand, and there are no guiding principles like Rails' `index` `new` `show` etc. conventions. `tl;dr:` you can achieve the same in Spring MVC/Roo, but you have to do it all by hand, whereas Rails has a nice DSL for routing, many guide-lines, and an awesome CLI

Comment: I know RoR. I want to switch to Java for android programming. Also, I want to develop web apps. Which one would you suggest? Which is better of Spring MVC or Grails? Which one is best for jobs and all? @John

Answer (score 2):

Have a good look at the the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/). I think that it's the best way to develop Java web applications at the moment. Certainly the quickest. There is no deploy cycle. Save the code and refresh the browser.

It comes with Hibernate and a host of enhanced functionality that streamlines the development process. Totally REST based and stateless.

Add in [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and it feels like web heaven.